# OneDrive files disappearing

Tags: onedrive

I have a bunch of files on my onedrive account synced with my laptop (windows 8.1) and Surface RT (Windows 8.1).

Now, if I add any files or folders (by web upload or by copying to onedrive folders on my laptop/Surface) all these files disappear from their location and I can find them in the Recycle Bin.

How can I troubleshoot this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try the feedback link from the options gear in the onedrive web page. They treat data loss issues very seriously and usually respond quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but I just ran across this (or a similar) issue and thought I'd share something that worked for me.

Check the following to see if the folders you've added to OneDrive are selected to be included in the sync:

1. Right-click the OneDrive icon in the taskbar and choose *Settings*
2. Go to the *Account* tab and click the *Choose folders* button
3. Select the checkbox for the folders you'd like to sync/save

NOTE:  If you are saving files directly in the OneDrive directory (*`C:\Users\YourName\OneDrive\`*) instead of in a folder (*`C:\Users\YourName\OneDrive\MyFolder\`*), make sure to check the box for the *"Files not in a folder"* option.